# Unable to layout all buttonfield in blackberry?

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

I am using four buttons in horizontal field manager which are each given a width of 1/4th of screen width still only 3 buttons are showing on the screen?
I am using blackberry 9900 simulator and blackberry plugin for eclipse.

```
    HorizontalFieldManager hm_btn_family = new HorizontalFieldManager();
    hm_btn_family.setMargin(10, 0, 0, 16);
    add(hm_btn_family);

    family = new Custom_buttonfield("Family", (Display.getWidth()/4), 40);
    family.setFont(font);
    hm_btn_family.add(family);

    friend = new Custom_buttonfield("Friends", (Display.getWidth()/4), 40);
    friend.setFont(font);
    hm_btn_family.add(friend);


    others = new Custom_buttonfield("Others", (Display.getWidth()/4), 40);
    others.setFont(font);
    hm_btn_family.add(others);

    calllist = new Custom_buttonfield("Call List", (Display.getWidth()/4), 40);
    calllist.setFont(font);
    hm_btn_family.add(calllist);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Display.getWidth()/4 assumes that the Manager you are adding it to has the full width of the Screen.  The width that is in fact available to it will depend on what it is allocated by the Manager it is added to (which is limited by its Manager and so on until you get back to the Screen).

It is also limited by the attributes of the Manager, specifically any margin or padding that you give the Manager.  In this case you do 'indent' the Manager by 16 pixels from the left when you do the following:

hm_btn_family.setMargin(10, 0, 0, 16)

So it seems that the maximum width for your buttons is probably Display.getWidth()/4 - 4.

But if you really want to do manage the size of Fields, you should actually do it in the sublayout method of the Manager it is being added to. So the best way to achieve this sort of size and placement involves creating your own Manager and laying things out yourself - for this you can review the following KB articles on the BB site:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-Extend-Manager/ta-p/446749

However in this case, I think I would recommend you just use one of the HorizontalFieldManagers that you be able to steal from this KB article, again on the BB site:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

Comment: yes thanks for reply, but if i am not setting the margins than still its not laying out the buttons in right way, if there are four button fields and i am assigning them 1/4th width of screen all the 4 must be visible and of same size but the same is not happening.

Comment: "if there are four button fields and i am assigning them 1/4th width of screen" - not necessarily, as noted above, you are assuming that the Manager you are adding it to has the full width of the Screen. Have you tried using a Manager from the samples I pointed you at, or looking at the code that uses to understand how you could layout something like this?